# How can I manually assembly a category-level product collection?

Tags: template, category, cms

I'm trying to display a category within a CMS page. (I know that a workaround would be to include a static block on a Category, but in this instance that is not an option for me). So I have this code in my CMS page:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/my_template.phtml"}}
```

Which is working correctly. Within that template file (`my_template.phtml`), I have a very similar setup to `app/design/frontend/core/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

But because this is being called from a CMS page, I'm not within the correct scope to use `$this`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

How can I manually set up the `$_productCollection` without access to `$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` - for instance, if I have an array of `$product_ids`, or a `$category_id`.

I've tried this approach:

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

But that is not able to call:

- `$_product->getRatingSummary()` (when looping through `$_productCollection` as `$_product`)
- `$this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short')`, or
- `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fits your needs, but by the looks of it, it should.
I've created [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products) that allows you to show product lists based on conditions. You can define a condition in the exact same way you define a cart rule.
You can choose to include the link to the rule page in the main menu.
It evens supports SEF URLs and layered navigation.

In your case you need to create such a rule and for conditions set `ID is one of` or `SKU is one of`.
Full documentation of the module [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products/wiki)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Really a great concept - and digging the SEF URLs. I'm surprised this functionality isn't native with Magento. I can only imagine it's quite a sought after feature. +1!

Comment: quick question. I'm trying to create a page without the layered navigation on the left hand side, so a single (1) column view. I don't see that being possible with this module, right?

Comment: By default all pages have 2-columns-left format. But you can edit `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/easylife_ruleproducts.xml` and make your page use one column.  Instead of `<update handle="page_two_columns_left" />` put `<update handle="page_one_column" />`. This will change the layout for all pages defined by rules. If you want different layouts for different rules you need to code. I'm considering adding this as a feature. I didn't do it so far, because the module is not that used, yet.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. P.S. I understand completely. It would definitely be a useful feature in future if you decide to continue development. Another possibility is also the ability to update layout XML inline, similarly to the `Design` tab of CMS pages.

Comment: @moose. At first I wanted to implement the Design feature of the categories, but I realized it is not needed for a minimum viable product. Now I'm considering adding it.